# How to optimize operations with non-contiguous memory access?

Tags: optimization, fortran, vectorization, memory-access

I'm trying to optimize a fortran code that uses data from non-contiguous memory locations, but that can be split so as to allow it, at the cost of an increased number of operations. The most readable way to present it is (writing with 2D arrays for simplicity, in the actual code it's extended to 3D):

```
do j=1,nj
  do i=1,ni
      r(i,j) = b(i,j) - c(i,j)*x(i,j) - d*(x(i-1,j)+x(i+1,j)+x(i,j-1)+x(i,j+1))
  end do
end do
```

where d is unknown at compile time. I'll be using array dimensions larger than 100 and accessing locations k-1 and k+1 inside this loop, resulting in large jumps across memory. Would it be better to split this into several loops (e.g. one for j-1, one for j+1, and so on) to take advantage of contiguous memory access (and possibly vectorization)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: (Have a look at the "kernel"s your processor (or compiler) vendor provides, if any. Intel is notorious for them.) (From memory of "research papers" on the subject: depends.)

Comment: There's a fair amount of prior art on the topic of *optimizing Fortran stencil codes*.  But the answer to almost all questions *Would it be better ... ?* (where *better* means *faster*) is *Test and measure ...*

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks for the reply! Will test and measure, and I've already found some literature regarding it, now that I know the proper name of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know your level of experience, but have you applied optimization? With GCC you should probaboly try `-O3 -march=native -flto`. Maybe further optimization isn't necessary?